# Does relative prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ also relative prime in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f,g$ be polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ which are coprime, does this implies $f,g$ are also coprime in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$?

Similarily if $f,g$ are coprime in $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ does this implies $f,g$ are coprime in $(\Bbb{C}(x))[y]$?

(I know some similar result that is if $f$ is premitive polynomial of positive degree then $f$ irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ also irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.)

---

As Magdiragdag point out

1. if $f,g$ relative prime is defined to be that $f,g$ do not share a common factor, then the implication does not hold
2. Another definition of being relative prime is given in [stack project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09GW#:%7E:text=Definition%209.11.,they%20have%20no%20common%20roots.) which is defined to be $(f)+(g) = (1)$, however it is only defined for the field(with two definitions coinside over field as we discussed in the comment.). If follow this definition the result holds trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. If $f, g$ are coprime in a ring $R$, that is $af+bg=1$ for some $a,b\in R$, then certainly it is still the case in any extension ring $R'\supset R$.

Comment: Not true for general rings. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Hi @lhf , sorry for the silly question can you provide a concrete example that $f,g$ relative prime in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ but not in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: $2$ and $x$ have no common factor but the ideal the generate is not the whole $\mathbb Z[x]$

Comment: thank you @lhf , you showed that relative prime elements needs not to generate the whole $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. however this seems not to be the example that I ask (I'm not sure) since $2,x$ has no common factor in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ but it also has no common factor in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$